# Javascript Regular Expression in dart

Tags: javascript, regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to get a regular expression that matches emojis working in dart. It seems to match all of them except for the english, scottish and welsh flags.

The emoji regex I am basing this off is https://www.regextester.com/106421 and have modified this to also match for ufe0f based on this github post https://github.com/petehouston/flutter-emoji/issues/8

I have created this dartpad which shows the problem

https://dartpad.dev/9b1a9c746ad4e567db36cbf3dab5bb49

Could someone please explain why this works in the js version and not in dart/flutter.

Thanks a lot

---

Edit for dartpad screen shot

[image]

Comment: Strings are UTF16 encoded in Dart. Try `String regexNew = r'[\u00a9\u00ae\u2000-\u3300\ufe0f--☀-⛿✀-➿]'`, or `String regexNew = r'[\u00a9\u00ae\u2000-\u3300\ufe0f-]'`

Comment: For the. first I get
Range out of order in character class[\u00a9\u00ae\u2000-\u3300\ufe0f--☀-⛿✀-➿]

For the second i get: The following FormatException was thrown running a test:
Range out of order in character class[\u00a9\u00ae\u2000-\u3300\ufe0f-]

Can you actually put emojis in the regex?

Comment: See https://dartpad.dev/9b1a9c746ad4e567db36cbf3dab5bb49

Comment: I don't think it saved. It still has my dartpad. You might have to create a gist and link it in the URL. See this https://gist.github.com/ and https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/wiki/Sharing-Guide

Comment: That is the same anyway, just the `String regexNew = r'[\u00a9\u00ae\u2000-\u3300\ufe0f-]';` is different, and the output is `English flag  =  Match true`

Comment: dartpad.dev/9b1a9c746ad4e567db36cbf3dab5bb49 - I am still getting this error. I will update with a screenshot. Sorry if I am being dumb.

Comment: Have you tried with `unicode: true`?

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't and that has fixed it, but it has broken all my tests for all the other emojis. My main aim is to get a BlacklistingTextInputFormatter that blocks all emojis on iOS and Android. The first regex was blocking all emojis that apart from the 3 british flags. Do you have.a solution that could achieve that?

Comment: Forgot to say I have updated the dartpad to have just the food emojis in aswell

Comment: Sorry, you mean you need a regex to match [any emoji](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html)?

Comment: Yes that is what I am after. Does that website include the different skin tone emojis that you can type on iOS? If it does then yes that is all of them. I basically need a regex to stop people typing emojis into text fields. Every one I have tried so far hasnt worked and its really getting me down.  it needs to match every one in a string incase they try pasting into the text field. Sorry I think i worded my question poorly

Comment: Do you have any ideas? @WiktorStribiżew